# Citrix Workspace Chrome extension keyboard layout messed up

Tags: 20.04, citrix

I am using Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS as host and Citrix Workspace Chrome extension (since it is the only installation that I got working with HDX).
Unfortunately, when I start the Windows 10 client I cannot use my keyboard because the key assignment seems random but consistent, meaning it is always the same but I cannot associate it with any country layout.
For example, key z gives y and vice versa, key "-" gives "ö" but key "ö" also gives "ö". "ß" is there twice as well...

Things I've tried:

- changing the layout on the client side. This did not work. Although in the taskbar it says "DEU" for German layout, the keyboard is still messed up.
- I changed the wfclient.ini (KeyboardLayout = German), but still not working (and I am not sure if this is only relevant for the Citrix Receiver installation)

I am not sure if cthe wfclient.ini file is for the Chrome Workspace App tbh.
Also I cannot find (through google and looking on my machine) a way to configure the Chrome Workspace App. So if anybody knows how to do it: please help!

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: What do you understand by "a scrambled keyboard layout"? Use "edit" and try to be more precise.

Comment: @vanadium I tried to be more specific. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced a similar issue using the Citrix WS app on Ubuntu:

- My keyboard layout on the host (Ubuntu) is set to a general Hungarian keyboard layout (correctly recognized as the real one)
- Same keyboard layout is set on the VM (Windows 10): Hungarian general
- When I type in the VM, it does not use the set layout, but some hybrid one (EN/HU mixed, EN where it has matching key with HU layout, HU, where it does not. I have HU letters, but special characters are mixed).
- When I use the On-screen keyboard of the VM, that shows the correct layout and works as expected.

The solution for me was that I needed to set the `LANGUAGE=hu_HU` environment variable (in `.bashrc`). Now the keyboard layout in Citrix is correct.

**NOTE** This might change the display language for other applications (e.g., MS Teams).

Another suggestion from the community was to update Chrome display language to the same as the keyboard layout. That might work, but for me, it was not necessary.